# sshpass with multiple commands BASH SCRIPT

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I want to create a bash script, which displays all data from mysql return.
The problem is, that i need to insert multiple commands e.g. "mysql -u root" => "use test" => "SELECT * FROM test"

i have tested it by creating 2 files. only the first file could be created.  Below are the versions how I have tested it. Does anybody have an idea how I can enter all commands after the row?
thank you for your attention.

Try 1

```
sshpass -p "" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx touch test/test1.txt & touch test2.txt
```

Try2

```
sshpass -p "" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx touch test/test1.txt && touch test2.txt
```

Try3

```
sshpass -p "" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx touch test/test1.txt; touch test2.txt;
```

Try4

```
sshpass -p "" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx touch test/test1.txt || touch test2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding sshpass, the better way to do it is to set up key-based ssh authentication so that you do not need to type password

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

regarding running multiple commands, you can do it by quote the commands and separate by ";", try

```
ssh user@server "echo \$HOSTNAME; echo \$SHELL"
```